# Ionic 6 android app with iframe only will get approved?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, webview

I have created ionic 6 app with iframe only which will show responsive version of website.

I need to help to confirm if i submit it on play store so they will approve ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt. specially Apple store might not approve it as the content is not controllable. you can change your website into anything Like: illegal content and apple will have no control over it. So they might not approve it. same for Google.

Comment: Yes i am sure apple will not approve but do you have idea on play store ? is there any article or some documentation ?